# SSL Rule Exception in ASP.NET web.config

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, ssl, url-rewriting

I have an SSL certificate and have set up a rewrite rule in my web.config to direct all traffic to https. This is working fine (code below if anyone finds it useful), however I now have a service I'm exposing to my phone clients and I DON'T want that to use HTTPS.

Can I create an exception? So any request for www.mydomain.com/PhoneService/Seek.svc is not re-directed to https://www.mydomain.com.....

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
          <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions>
                  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
          </rule>
      </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use another condition to your rule to ensure that the path does not end in `seek.svc`:

```
<rules> 
  <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
      <match url="(.*)" /> 
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="seek\.svc$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" /> 
      </conditions> 
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" /> 
  </rule> 
</rules>
```

The line:

```
<add input="{URL}" pattern="seek\.svc$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
```

checks the `URL` variable and ends with `seek.svc`. We negate the condition because we only want the rule to apply if it *doesn't* match.

Comment: Note: I edited it from {PATH_INFO} to {URL} as [that is more correct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Brilliant, just what I was after.